# Trouble with DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA not firing

Tags: actionscript-3

I am having some trouble with an AS3 script to upload data to the server via PHP and then return some values from the PHP upload script. I am using the FileReference.upload() function, and the files are being successfully uploaded, but the eventListener I attached to the DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA event is not triggering. Is there something I can do on the PHP end of things to manually trigger this event when the file is done uploading?

as3:

```
private function onFileLoaded(event:Event):void {
            //var _fileReference:FileReference = event.target as FileReference;
            //var data:ByteArray = fileReference["data"];
            //var filename:String = fileReference.name;
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.arttoframes.com/canvasSystems/uploadImage.php");
                urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;                  
            fileReference.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, onUploadComplete);
            fileReference.upload(urlRequest);
        }
        private function onFileLoadError(event:Event):void  {
            fileReference.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
            fileReference.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileLoadError); 
        } 
  private function onUploadComplete(event:Event):void {
            trace("ok");
            fileReference.removeEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA,onUploadComplete);
            var thumbReferenceName = fileReference.name.substr(0,fileReference.name.indexOf("."))+"_thumb"+fileReference.name.substr(fileReference.name.indexOf("."),4)+"?nocache=" + new Date().getTime()
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.arttoframes.com/canvasSystems/uploads/Thumbnails/"+thumbReferenceName);
            var urlLoader:Loader = new Loader ();
                urlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDownloadComplete);
                //urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is a long standing bug that Adobe claims they've fixed, but at least in Flex 3 lots of people claim they can reproduce it even after Adobe says they've fixed it.  And that's including yours truly.

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1419

I'd employ a work around monitoring the progress directly and when all of it has uploaded manually dispatch the event or just do your work there.  There are several work arounds you can try reading the comments in Jira.

Comment: Wow, this is stopping my project dead in it's tracks. The DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA is the only way for me to get URLvar data BACK from the upload script. Monitoring progress won't work because it does not return data from PHP. Anyone else had any luck working around this?

Comment: There are other work arounds included in the Jira ticket that talk about what you can do to get URL data back, but you probably will have to restructure the way  you are doing things.  Possibly saving that data to the session and making a second call to retrieve it.  Not how we want to solve this, but you can work around this problem.

Comment: I know the entire flash technology stack is pretty much deprecated now, but I had this same issue - it turned out my file was failing to upload due to being larger than the php.ini configured upload_max_filesize maximum. It also appears DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA doesn't trigger if nothing is echoed / no response is generated.